# Search in tree structure JSON data

Tags: json, angular, typescript, treeview

I am building dynamic menu in a tree structure with the search option.

JSON Data looks like below:

```
directories = [
            {
                name: 'parent1',
                child: [{
                    name: 'child1',
                    child: [{
                        name: 'child2',
                        child: []
                    }]
                },
                {
                    name: 'child2',
                    child: []
                }]
            },
            {
                name: 'parent2',
                child: [{
                    name: 'child1',
                    child: []
                }]
            },
            {
                name: 'parent2',
                child: [{
                    name: 'child1',
                    child: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'child2',
                    child: []
                }]
            }
        ];
    }
```

Below code to search items in parent node level:

```
searchFilter(search: string) {
        console.log(search);
        this.filteredArray = this.directories.filter(item => {
            if (item.name.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        );
        console.log(this.filteredArray);
    }
```

I am calling above code on keyup event and it returns the search result on the parent node level.

Now I want to do search till the nth child. Any help?

Comment: You need a recursive implementation for that, also, you should rename `child` property for `children` because this way you instantly know that it's an `array`.

Comment: Can you explain in terms of code for recursion perspective

Comment: I provided an example in my answer above, but basically instead of going into the array using one level (that's what filter does) you go deeper inside to return the first matching element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive implementation for your filter, something like:

```
function searchFilter(search: string, directories: any[]) {
    for(let directory of directories){
        if(directory.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(search)){
            return directory;
        }
        if (directory.child !== undefined && directory.child.length > 0) {
            let childsearch = searchFilter(search, directory.child)
            if (childsearch !== undefined) {
                return childsearch
            }
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

[see on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Alet%20d%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'a'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'aa'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'aaa'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'aab'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'b'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'ba'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20searchFilter(search%3A%20string%2C%20directories%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for(let%20directory%20of%20directories)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(directory.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(search))%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20directory%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(directory.child%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%20%26%26%20directory.child.length%20%3E%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20childsearch%20%3D%20searchFilter(search%2C%20directory.child)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(childsearch%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20childsearch%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(searchFilter('ba'%2C%20d))%3B)

Another approach is possible to return every matching item in your array (act like a nth-depth filter):

```
function searchFilter(search: string, directories: any[], results = []) {
    for(let directory of directories){
        if(directory.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(search)){
            results.push(directory);
        }
        if (directory.child !== undefined && directory.child.length > 0) {
            let childsearch = searchFilter(search, directory.child)
            if (childsearch !== undefined) {
                results = results.concat(childsearch);
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

[see on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Alet%20d%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'a'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'aa'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'aaa'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'aab'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'b'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'ba'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20searchFilter(search%3A%20string%2C%20directories%3A%20any%5B%5D%2C%20results%20%3D%20%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for(let%20directory%20of%20directories)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(directory.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(search))%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20results.push(directory)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(directory.child%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%20%26%26%20directory.child.length%20%3E%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20childsearch%20%3D%20searchFilter(search%2C%20directory.child)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(childsearch%20!%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20results%20%3D%20results.concat(childsearch)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20results%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(searchFilter('a'%2C%20d))%3B)

Comment: @VigneshwaranMarkandan I edited the example to fix the recursion behavior, it now works correctly.

Comment: Thanks, will try this

Answer (score 3):

This will look inside the whole tree and provide an array with all the corresponding results

```
searchFilter2(search: string, directories: any[]) {
  let results = [];
  for (let directory of directories) {
      if (directory.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(search)) {
        results.push(directory);
      }
      if (directory.child && directory.child.length > 0) {
        results = [...results, ...this.searchFilter2(search, directory.child)];
      }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this

Answer (score 0):

base on @Lejendarm answer, i change like this:

```
searchFilter(search: string, directories: any[]) {
      let results = [];
       for (let directory of directories) {
          if (directory.title.toLowerCase().includes(search)) {
            results.push(directory);
          } else if (directory.child && directory.child.length > 0) {
            let foundedNodes = this.searchFilter(directory.child);
            if (foundedNodes.length > 0) {
              directory.kids = foundedNodes;
              results = results.concat([directory]);
            }
          }
          
    return results;
 }
```