# how to loop through an array of object in Tree Node

Tags: jquery, typescript

i want to convert my data into specific Tree Node format.

Is there a way (typescript or Jquery) to loop through each object and it's children and grandchildren and so on and change the format?

> Current data format

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "dimension": "2019-12-13"
      "subList": [
        {
          "dimension": "2019-12-13",
          "subList": [
            {
              "dimension": "2019-12-13",
              "subList": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dimension": "2019-12-13"
      "subList": [
        {
          "dimension": "2019-12-13",
          "subList": [
            {
              "dimension": "2019-12-13",
              "subList": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

so the result should be like this

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "data": {
        "dimension": "2019-12-13"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "data": {
            "dimension": "2019-12-13"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "data": {
                "dimension": "2019-12-13"
              },
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Hi go through the link may help you   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546157/search-in-tree-structure-json-data

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're dealing with a tree-like data structure, you probably want a recursive function.

Let's formalise the types we're dealing with:

```
type Node1 = { // current node structure
  dimension: string
  subList: Node1[]
}

type Node2 = { // desired node structure
  data: {
    dimension: string
  }
  children: Node2[]
}
```

Your recursive function will look something like this:

```
const mapNode = (n: Node1): Node2 => {
  return {
    data: {
      dimension: n.dimension
    },
    children: n.subList.map(mapNode)
  }
}
```